# Add an object to an Array of a custom class

Tags: java, arrays

Im a beginner to Java and I'm trying to create an array of a custom class.
Let say I have a class called car and I want to create an array of cars called Garage. How can I add each car to the garage? This is what I've got:

```
car redCar = new Car("Red");
car Garage [] = new Car [100];
Garage[0] = redCar;
```

Comment: Naming conventions: variables start with lower case and objects with upper case: `Car redCar = ...`, `Car[] garage = ...`, `garage[0]` etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to use an array, you have to keep a counter which contains the number of cars in the garage. Better use an `ArrayList` instead of array:

```
List<Car> garage = new ArrayList<Car>();
garage.add(redCar);
```

Comment: And how can I get a particular car in the garage? Like how do I get the first car added?

Comment: +1 for the list suggestion :). The next step would be to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` and use a `Set<Car>` (since it might not make much sense for exactly the same car to be in a garage twice :) ).

Comment: @Dangerosking - Use `garage.get(0)`

Comment: *"And how can I get a particular car in the garage?"* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Can the arraylist be used in a abstract class? Just like the array, I can create it but I can't add an object to it.

Answer (score 12):

The array declaration should be:

```
Car[] garage = new Car[100];
```

You can also just assign directly:

```
garage[1] = new Car("Blue");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create a garage and fill it up with new cars that can be accessed later, use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < garage.length; i++)
     garage[i] = new Car("argument");
```

Also, the cars are later accessed using:

```
garage[0];
garage[1];
garage[2];
etc.
```