# Add object to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

I have an object array like this

```
Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[]{
                MovieCreator.build(filList.get(0)),
                MovieCreator.build(filList.get(1)),
                MovieCreator.build(filList.get(2))};
```

Now How do I dynamically add to inMovies all the elements of Arraylist filList.

I tried this but not working

```
List<Movie> movi = new ArrayList<Movie>();
for (String path : filList) {
movi.add(MovieCreator.build(path));
}
Movie[] inMovies = movi.toArray();
```

Comment: How about using toArray() method of ArrayList class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add an object to an Array of a custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400373/add-an-object-to-an-array-of-a-custom-class)

Comment: What do you mean that "it's not working"?

Comment: The error is incompatible types Required: com.googlecode...movie   found:java.lang.object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use arrays. Use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
List<Movie> inMovies = new ArrayList<>();
inMovies.add(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean with dynamically?

if you just want an array out of a list use:

```
Movies[] inMovies = filList.toArray(new Movies[filList.size()]);
```

(... just saw what u tried ...)

You have to specify the type of the Array to which you want to convert the list. For that you have to set the type of array as parameter in the `toArray(T[] x)` method ... like shown above

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
 List<Movie> inMovies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
   for (String path : filList) {
   inMovies.add(MovieCreator.build(path));
   }
```